# ionic angularFire App Controller is executed without onClick="method()" being called

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

the controller get executed before i could even click the the ng-cliclk="logout()" how can i prevent this

JS:

```
.controller('logOutCtrl', function($scope, taskref, $state) {
  if (taskref.unauth()) {
    $state.go('tabsController.pendingTasks');
  } else {
    $state.go('login');
  }
})
```

Template:

```
<ion-list data-componentid="list5">
  <ion-item ui-sref="settings" menu-close="" data-componentid="list-item9">Settings</ion-item>
  <ion-item ui-sref="reminders" menu-close="" data-componentid="list-item10">Help &amp; Reminders</ion-item>
  <ion-item ui-sref="login" menu-close="" ng-controller="logOutCtrl" ng-cliclk="logout()" data-componentid="list-item12">Log out</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller is also like a function which executes when we use it with `ng-controller`. So You should create the `$scope.logout()` function in `logOutCtrl` and add related logout code in that function instead of writing code openly in controller.

Modified Controller:

```
.controller('logOutCtrl', function($scope, taskref, $state) {
      $scope.logout = function(){
          if (taskref.unauth()) {
            $state.go('tabsController.pendingTasks');
          } else {
            $state.go('login');
          }
      }
 })
```

Modified Template:

```
<ion-list data-componentid="list5">
  <ion-item ui-sref="settings" menu-close="" data-componentid="list-item9">Settings</ion-item>
  <ion-item ui-sref="reminders" menu-close="" data-componentid="list-item10">Help &amp; Reminders</ion-item>
  <ion-item ui-sref="login" menu-close="" data-componentid="list-item12">Log In</ion-item>
  <ion-item  menu-close="" ng-controller="logOutCtrl" ng-click="logout()" data-componentid="list-item12">Log out</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```